# not been able to make Jenkins trigger a build when changes are pushed to Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

their are a lot of question like this but none seem to work.

I am running jenkins on `http://localhost:1001/` and have added the authorization token from github into jenkins and it seems to work.

I can build the project manually and when i push some thing onto the github and build the project again changes are made but

I am not been able to do this automatically via webhook.

when I open last github log this is the output

> Polling has not run yet

in configuration of project I have put

[image]

PS: don't worry that i have posted the link repo because their is nothing much in repo.

PPS: installed all the plug ins and build trigger is on Build when a change is pushed to GitHub

Comment: Is your jenkins accessible from the internet? The Github webhook is supposed to acces your jenkins instance to trigger the build.

Comment: @JosueAbarca jenkins I am using jenkins in localhost. so no.

Comment: @JosueAbarca so there is no way that i can webhook my local machine to github

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your jenkins is not accessible from a public IP address, GitHub can not trigger the build via WebHook.

The alternative is to use the  "Polling" mechanism, to check for changes every X minutes, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can webhook even your local machine using services that provide tunnels from some endpoint on the web and the local Jenkins installation. Like, [UltraHook](http://www.ultrahook.com/), for instance. I've solved the same problem using these steps:

- Register on UltraHook (it is free) and get your API key and domain in the system
- Install UltraHook gem on your local machine:

  > gem install ultrahook
- In GitHub repository specify the URL to send a webhook to.  It should be the URL provided by UltraHook (like http://repository_name.your_subdomain.ultrahook.com)
- Run ultrahook on the local machine and you are done:

  > ultrahook [-k ] subdomain destination

However, other solutions, like [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com) might be more reliable (at least it has no problems with long uptimes, unlike the ultrahook)